# Storing Procedure in a Pair (Scheme/Guile)

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, guile

I am working in Guile, and need to use a procedure that is stored in a pair. If I store `car` in the following examples:

```
(define pairA (cons 1 car))
(define pairB '(1 . car))
```

.. I can only evaluate the procedure from the first expression. The second is turned into a symbol, I'm guessing somehow due to it being in a pair but not a list:

```
>(display pairA)
(1 . #<primitive-procedure car>)

>(display pairB)
(1 . car)
```

Why does the first example return `car` as a procedure, but not the second one? The only difference I can tell is that `pairA` is both a list/pair, and `pairB` is only a pair. Is there some way to use `(cdr pairB)` as a procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is

```
`(1 . ,car)
```

This is the quasiquote construct -- in short, it evaluates only car (in general -- only the unquoted "," expressions), and inserts its value in the position of unquoted form. One more small example:

```
scheme@(guile-user)> `(quasiquote magic (+ 2 3) => ,(+ 2 3))
$1 = (quasiquote magic (+ 2 3) => 5)
```

Your first example worked because cons is a procedure (i.e. not a special form) so it's arguments are evaluated prior to application. The second did not work, because you had (1 . car) quoted.

Note also that your pairA is NOT a list -- procedures are not represented as lists, they are atoms:

```
scheme@(guile-user)> (pair? car)
$1 = #f
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I couldn't find anything in the docs about working with expressions this way before, but see now how it works. If I can't change how the list is constructed, is there anyway to read `'(1 . car)` as if it were quasi/unquoted? I'm working with a program that has a specific list-building infrastructure, that basically takes user input and makes a bunch of alists without considering whether the values are procedures, symbols, numbers, etc.

Comment: @JefferyShivers User input can't actually specify functions. Unless you want `car` in the user input to actually map to the `car` procedure: in that case, you might want a symbol-to-procedure hashtable (or alist, if small). The alist would look like this: `\`((car . ,car) (cdr . ,cdr) ...)`. (This is a bit difficult to explain in detail in a comment box, but I'll be happy to try to explain anything that you ask about.)

Comment: Thanks @Chris, that makes sense! Writing the alist like you show works perfectly.